# How to deploy a Java Play App in production using a Windows environment?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, playframework, playframework-2.6

I have built a Java Play app using the latest version. Currently I am running the application using the batch file that gets generated. There's a zip file created inside target->universal folder (When I go to the bin folder inside the extracted folder this batch file is available).

How can I run this in production Windows environment? This play app is a backend service that needs to run continuously. Should this be created as a Windows Service? As in, should I try to run this batch file as a Windows Service through some means? I can't find any online references on this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are [service wrappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_wrapper) available, that can take almost any arbitrary application and run it as a service or daemon on some operating systems.  I would highly recommend that you avoid them.  Writing secure, performant services for Windows is not trivial.  You can however run any script using [Windows TaskManager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323527/how-to-use-and-troubleshoot-issues-with-windows-task-manager) (GUI) or [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx), and it has all the knobs you need to easily control how your application runs, when it starts and what to do if it crashes.

See [schtasks.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx) for command line interface reference.